# 400 Error when doing Spring Rest Post

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Web service that I have to do a Post. This is the current signature.

```
ScreenResult sendScreenAsPostcard(@RequestParam String listOfRecipients, @RequestParam String message, @RequestParam String userId, @RequestParam String captcha, @RequestParam MultipartFile image)
```

A Flash application is calling this. I am using the front end and using Firebug to look at parameters. When I pass this. I get

400 Bad Request.

When I change the signature just to make sure I can hit it all,

```
ScreenResult sendScreenAsPostcard(@RequestBody string)
```

and print in the string. It hits the service and I believe it is able to read the parameters although I am not sure if it reads the multipart file accurately. My question is what I am doing wrong?

The flash application is passing JSON.

This is relevant part of the body.

```
Content-type: application/json Accept: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"


{"listOfRecipients":"","message":"","captcha":"","image":"RldTCBf+AAB4AAXcAAARlAAADAEAfxEEAAAACAAAAL8W4f0AAAEA2/0AAAAA/9n/2P/Y/+AAEEpGSUYAAQIBAEgASAAA/","userId":""}
```

Comment: Try running your web app in a debugger, and putting a breakpoint in your `HandlerExceptionResolver`. Whatever is being used to bind parameters should be throwing an exception that passes through this class.

Answer (score 1):

`@RequestParam` is about HTTP GET/POST parameters. And you don't have such parameters, so your submit is a "bad request". On the other hand your request body can be converted to an object (it's JSON), so the 2nd one works.

What you need is a class that has the fields `listOfRecipients`, `message`, `captcha`, `image` and have `.. handle(@RequestBody YourObject obj)`

Comment: Trying this way I get a 415 Unsupported media type which is actually a positive step, but not sure what that is referring to.

Comment: try specifying `headers="Accept: application/json"` in the request mapping.

Comment: First off thanks for your help. A lot of progress thanks to you but one thing is I got a 500 maybe error when I use a multipart file. Does multipart have to be handled differently?

Comment: certainly. In your case, however, it looks like base64 encoded string. So you don't need multipart. Just get it as string and turn the base64 to `byte[]`

Comment: Would I have to use a MultipartHttpServletRequest. Reason I am asking is that I know this issue will come up. I didn't know if I had to do some things regarding message converters etc. Really can't thank you enough for your help.

Comment: No, go without MultpartHttpXX.. the request is JSON, not multipart. Look at commons-codec for base64 decoding

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar error and found that I set a field to string which should be a number. After I correct it, the post became successful. :)